# ImageCache on s3 not generating

Tags: media

I am using `putObjectFile` to move images form local to s3 bucket.
Source image is moving fine. After moving, I am updating its `uri`, `filename` in `file_managed` table.
But I am unable to see its image styles on s3 bucket.
When I opne the node, checkin in firbug, it shows me the path from local server say `local.site.com/s3/files/styles/thumbnail/s3/legacy/2015/1429522593_1974262741.jpg` while `1429522593_1974262741.jpg` is new name on s3.

I am using putObjectFile as

`$s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket, $actual_image_name_directory, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)`

which is working fine.

I have tried using `image_style_create_derivative` to create on s3. But it changes nothing.

When I view the node, then look in dblog it shows for example.

`Unable to generate an image derivative at s3://styles/thumbnail/s3/legacy/2015/1429522593_1974262741.jpg.`

Comment: Did you progress with this? What module is creating the derivatives? We're having similar problems with S3FS and EPSACrop.